# file_put_contents on localhost on Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, permissions, mamp

I try to create SVG's with the following code:

```
<?php

$codes = file('someFile.txt');

foreach ($codes as $code) {

    ob_start();


echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';

?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="2075px" height="775px" viewBox="0 0 2075 775" enable-background="new 0 0 2075 775" xml:space="preserve">
</svg>
<?php 

    if (file_put_contents("/out/".$code.".svg", ob_get_clean()) === false) {
        echo "error\n";
    }
}


?>
```

For this I use MAMP on Mac OS X.
In my browser I see "error" a lot of times so `file_put_contents` is likely to go wrong.

The permissions of the folder where my php file is located are set like this:
[image: permissions]

I also have set the permissions like this:
[image: permissions terminal]

I'm expecting the files to come in the `out` folder in the htdocs of MAMP in the folder where the php file is located. So for this example: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/NEXT_Logo_001` Is this correct?

Long story short, I don't have any files at the moment and I have no clue what to do.
Someone ideas?

Comment: Try `./out` instead of `/out`

Comment: Yeah, that's your problem you are specifying an absolute path in your file_put_contents call.

Comment: long with that, I found it, the out folder didn't exist. I thought it would be created if it didn't exist as it does in processing (www.processing.org).